# TypeError: string indices must be integers when extracting values from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when using the following code to return the values from a key in a dictionary:

```
ids_batch = [x['acn_num_ACN'] for x in meta_batch]
ids_batch
```

The dictionary (`meta_batch`) is structured as:

```
{'acn_num_ACN': ['1107876', '1784088', '1216003'], 'Time_Date': ['201308', '202012', '201411']}
```

I appreciate I can get the values of the given key by using `meta_batch['acn_num_ACN']` however, I feel the initial code should work... Grateful of any insight!

Comment: So what exactly does `meta_batch` look like?

Comment: Good point - sorry! Have updated the question

Comment: for used against a dictionary works over the keys so conceptually you are asking for `"acn_num_ACN"["acn_num_ACN"]`.  You might want to look at `meta_batch.values()` and/or `meta_batch.items()` or in this case just `meta_batch["acn_num_ACN"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in your list comprehension are strings, not dictionaries. You can index (with integer indexes) into strings, but strings have no keys. That's what the error message is telling you.

```
meta_batch = {'acn_num_ACN': ['1107876', '1784088', '1216003'], 'Time_Date': ['201308', '202012', '201411']}

meta_batch_keys = [x for x in meta_batch]
print(meta_batch_keys)
# ['acn_num_ACN', 'Time_Date']

meta_batch_keys_types = [type(x) for x in meta_batch]
print(meta_batch_keys_types)
# [<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]

meta_batch_keys_substrs = [x[0:2] for x in meta_batch]
print(meta_batch_keys_substrs)
# ['ac', 'Ti']
```

You need this, probably:

```
meta_batch = {'acn_num_ACN': ['1107876', '1784088', '1216003'], 'Time_Date': ['201308', '202012', '201411']}
ids_batch = meta_batch['acn_num_ACN']
print(ids_batch)
# ['1107876', '1784088', '1216003']

# or convert strings to integers:
ids_batch = [int(i) for i in meta_batch['acn_num_ACN']]
print(ids_batch)
# [1107876, 1784088, 1216003]
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear. I have another section of code; 

`meta_batch = [{
        'acn_num_ACN': i['acn_num_ACN'],
        'Time_Date': i['Time_Date'],
} for i in meta_batch]`
        
To avoid a type error, is it correct to put `int(i)['acn_num_ACN']` in place of `i['acn_num_ACN']`?

Comment: I would ask this as a separate question, this way you get more and faster replies.